# How to run H2O.ai on top of SQL

Tags: h2o

The folks over at H2O.ai mention in several slides and documents that H2O.ai can run on top of SQL. How do I connect my H2O.ai instance to a SQL Server? The only suggestion I could find so far looks rather disappointing: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/x8BLSGbyvhA

Is there a more elegant way to connect directly to a SQL Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

H2O does not have a native JDBC connector (yet).

You can leverage H2O's algorithms in Spark w/ Sparkling Water though (https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water): use Spark SQL to ingest data into an RDD, convert it to an H2OFrame (you can convert in either direction), and pass it to H2O's algos.

A more blunt approach is to query the data out into a CSV, which H2O can then read. If your data size is not too massive this may be reasonable.